# C++: seeding random number per Stroustrup's examples

Tags: c++

I'm using small modifications Stroustrup's C++ examples for random numbers in C++ 4th Ed Page 127-130.

I'm having trouble modifying the example on Page 130 below to use a non-deterministic random seed.  I get warning when adding in the code `re{rd}` in `Rand_int`s constructor.  I have included the warnings but am unsure what they mean or how to resolve them.  Does anyone know?

Page 130 modified code to use non-deterministic random number:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

class Rand_int {
public:
    Rand_int(int low, int high) :dist{low,high}, re{rd()} { }
    int operator()() { return dist(re); } // draw an int
private:
    random_device rd;
    default_random_engine re;
    uniform_int_distribution<> dist;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Rand_int rnd {1, 6};

    vector<int> hist(7);

    for (int i=0; i<200; i++)
        ++hist[rnd()];

    for (size_t i=1; i<hist.size(); i++) {
        cout << i << '\t';
        for (int j=0; j!=hist[i]; ++j)
            cout << '*';
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Warnings:

```
test93.cc:13:32: warning: ‘Rand_int::dist’ will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
     uniform_int_distribution<> dist;
                                ^~~~
test93.cc:12:27: warning:   ‘std::default_random_engine Rand_int::re’ [-Wreorder]
     default_random_engine re;
                           ^~
test93.cc:8:5: warning:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
     Rand_int(int low, int high) :dist{low,high}, re{rd()} { }
     ^~~~~~~~
1   ********************************
2   *********************************
3   *************************************
4   ****************************************
5   ********************************
6   **************************
```

Code from Page 127 and 128 that worked to generate non-deterministic random number:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    using engine = default_random_engine;
    using distribution = uniform_int_distribution<>;

    random_device rd;  // for seed
    engine re{rd()};

    distribution dist {1,6};
    auto rand = bind(dist, re);

    vector<int> hist(7);

    for (int i=0; i<200; i++)
        ++hist[rand()];

    for (size_t i=1; i<hist.size(); i++) {
        cout << i << '\t';
        for (int j=0; j!=hist[i]; ++j)
            cout << '*';
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is bad: `using namespace std;`.  Don't do that.  You've used `vector<int>`, but you don't `#include <vector>`; that's bad too.  You've used `size_t`, but you've not `#include`'d any of the 7 header files that declare `size_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that the data members of `Rand_int` will be initialized in the order that they are declared (`rd`, then `re`, then `dist`) but that this does not match the order in which you have specified them in the constructor's initializer list:

```
dist{low,high}, re{rd()}
```

This warning is intended to alert you to the fact that `re` is initialized before `dist` even though you have specified them in the opposite order.  To fix this, just reorder the initializer list:

```
re{rd()}, dist{low,high}
```

This doesn't change the behavior of the program, it just silences the compiler warning.  The warning is there because the initialization order can matter (here it matters that `rd` is initialized before `re`, for example) and the incorrect order in the initializer list can indicate that you expect initialization to happen in a different order than it actually is.

Answer (score 2):

Members of a class are initialized in the order that they are declared, regardless of the order you initialize them in the member initializer list. The compiler error is quite specific, and points out that you should write:

```
Rand_int(int low, int high) : re{rd()}, dist{low,high} { }
```